# How to use jstree v3 plugin with reorder only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree, jstree-dnd

I am using  jsTree V3.0.8 (http://www.jstree.com/)

how to reorder only when use dnd plugin like at V1(http://johntang.github.io/JsTree/_docs/dnd.html#demo2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `check_callback` option like this:

```
"check_callback" : function (op, node, par, pos, more) {
    if(more && more.dnd) {
        return more.pos !== "i" && par.id == node.parent;
    }
    return true;
},
```

Here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/509/

Comment: Works wonderful! +1. Many people are still getting hit on the CRRM example....sadly...